# Android 6.0 shows up contacts from all accounts

Tags: contacts, phone-app, 6.0-marshmallow

My Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 shows up all contacts from all my accounts in dialer (including Exchange). I only want to see contacts from my gmail.

I already went to contact application and selected only gmail, but it does not work. I posted this question somewhere on google forum and they said they will fix it in 6.0, but now I cannot find this forum and the issue posted.

**Update:** Finally found the forum: [google developers](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=dialer%20contacts&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles). I cannot believe this issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: Presumably you're looking for a fix in the meantime?

Comment: Correct, I need a fix

Comment: This is the correct link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81168

Comment: Thank you. It is already 6.0.1 and the issue is still there. I do not care about material design and visual features and I need functional phone.

Answer (score 2):

In Android 6.0 Marshmallow version there are 2 ways to see only contact list.

1st click and open contact
 And 
In this list from heading select, click and open Record 
Or
Directly open phone list
Then to view only contacts 
Then there is only one way as under to view only all contact lists without Emails lists.
You just simply type name of your contact saved in your phone book list 
And 
With displaying phone number to be dialed
It will simultaneously display only names without Email list with scrutinized and screening